# Spot Instances Support DCOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mesosphere

Is it possible to change the DCOS template to use spot instances? I have looked around and there does not seem to be much information regarding this.

Comment: can you provide code, or at least a link to it? (e.g., the cloudformation template)

Comment: Sure, https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mesosphere.io/dcos/stable/single-master.cloudformation.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, [given the DCOS template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mesosphere.io/dcos/stable/single-master.cloudformation.json), the LaunchConfiguration for the slaves looks like this: (I've shortened it somewhat)

```
"MasterLaunchConfig": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "MasterInstanceProfile" },
    "SecurityGroups": [ ... ],
    "ImageId": { ... },
    "InstanceType": { ... },
    "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
    "UserData": { ... }
  }
}
```

To get started, all you need to do is add the [`SpotPrice`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-spotprice) property in there. The value of `SpotPrice` is, obviously, the maximum price you want to pay. You'll probably need to do more work around autoscaling, especially with alarms and time of day. So here's your new `LaunchConfiguration` with a spot price of $1.00 per hour:

```
"MasterLaunchConfig": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "MasterInstanceProfile" },
    "SecurityGroups": [ ... ],
    "ImageId": { ... },
    "InstanceType": { ... },
    "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
    "UserData": { ... },
    "SpotPrice": 1.00
  }
}
```